# Crystal.NET - Localization of date fields within Cross-Tab

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I have a **date field in a Crystal Report which is set to use the format "System Default Short Format" and this localizes successfully**.

For example, I end up with a date like `27/12/2014 1:23:45p.m`.

However, the **seconds are meaningless for this particular report so I would like to omit them AND still have the date localize**.

I can do this using the code below at run-time for regular reports....it just doesn't work for a cross-tab report:

```
field.FieldFormat.CommonFormat.EnableUseSystemDefaults = false;
field.FieldFormat.TimeFormat.SecondFormat =
          CrystalDecisions.Shared.SecondFormat.NumericNoSecond;
```

Does anyone know a way of doing this either at design time/runtime for a cross-tab?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks...but then you are specifying a fixed format. I need the date format to localize according to the regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ToText function in the formula.

```
ToText({datefield},”dd-MMM-yyyy”)
```

See http://crystaltricks.com/wordpress/?p=149.